# screen resoultion when moving up to tablets

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed a business app that runs fine on android phone. What do i need to do the screen designs (xml files) so it will scale up for example 10" tablets? but still be okay on the phone?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked a general questions so the best I can do is give you a general answer. You should read the android documentation on [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: for example my screen lookds ok on the phone but when run on the tablet the text are to small and the layout is not correct.